# Why do gene therapies so often target rare disease?

Tags: gene-therapy

I read on {1}:

> At the time of writing, clinicaltrials.gov has well over 100 open gene therapy clinical trials and many of these are for rare diseases.

Why do gene therapies so often target rare disease? Economically it would seems to make more sense to first address common diseases. Do rare diseases tend to have some properties that make them more inclined to be treated via gene therapy?

---

References:

- {1} Ekins, Sean. "Industrializing rare disease therapy discovery and development." Nature biotechnology 35, no. 2 (2017): 117. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5320585/ ; https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2Fnbt.3787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common diseases *tend* to be polyfactorial, while rare genetic diseases *often* involve a single gene. Many involve just a single mutation event (substitution, deletion, addition, inversion, etc).

It's easier to target a single-gene defect than multiple. Since gene therapies are at such an early stage of development, it's expected they would go for low-hanging fruit.

---

Go to [clinicaltrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/) and search for [gene therapy](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=gene+therapy+genetic). Consider the genetic interventions (skip the drug trials). The majority on the first dozen pages specify a *single* target gene.

I was unable to find a list of non-infectious diseases ranked by prevalence. However, there is a [List of Common Diseases](https://www.ranker.com/list/list-of-common-diseases-most-common-illnesses/diseases-and-medications-info) on Ranker. It is suitable for illustrative purposes. Scrolling through the index of a textbook would do as well. Skipping psychiatric, infectious, and situational conditions (such as traumatic brain injury), consider whether there is an obvious genetic target. There isn't one for conditions such as Dementia, Diabetes Mellitus, Cancer, Stroke, etc.

Also consider [CDC: Leading Causes of Death](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/leading-causes-of-death.htm). They're largely non-genetic.

DM-II is highly heritable, so in that sense, it is genetic. But usually, people consider only single-gene conditions to be "genetic". So what are some "common" genetic diseases? This [infographic](https://www.labroots.com/trending/infographics/8833/10-common-genetic-diseases) lists ten. Note that they're *not* that common compared with non-genetic diseases. Six of them *do* have genetic therapy trials. The rest have drug trials, so they're not being ignored. These are the ones that don't have genetic therapy trials listed:

- [Down Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_syndrome). Usually trisomy 21. Excising an entire extra chromosome is *likely* beyond current gene therapy capabilities. Another cause is translocation. In that case, half a chromosome would have to be excised.
- [Fragile-X Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_X_syndrome). Triplet repeat of variable length. Variability *likely* complicates gene therapy. For instance, how to excise a repeat that is too long vs a repeat that is normal?
- [Huntington Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntington%27s_disease). Triplet repeat of variable length. There is also a psychosocial issue where many with Huntington [do not want to know their status](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/cge.13529). How do you treat a population that is in denial? There is a [documentary](http://www.doyoureallywanttoknowfilm.com/the-film/) about it.
- [Angelman Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelman_syndrome). Caused by uniparental disomy. Two copies of chromosome 15 are inherited from the father. The extra copy would have to be replaced with a chromosome from the mother.

Comment: Thank you, follow-up question: [Why do common disease tend to be polyfactorial, while rare diseases often involve a single gene?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/19338/43)